# how to create a project in php strom from an IP address locally

Tags: phpstorm-2017.1

I have a problem that I want to share with you for getting help from you. I have PHP Storm installed on my local PC suppose the IP address of this is 192.168.1.115 and I have server installation at another PC in my Local Network suppose the IP of server is 192.168.1.3. Now Question is how can I connect or create a project from my local network server (192.168.1.3) to my local PC (192.168.1.115). I use all the options which are available in PHP Storm for creating a new project from existing files but I'm not able to fetch any data from any other computer in my local network. Even the "Select Path" dialog box is not able to show me my network shared folders. On the other hand, I can create project from my local network server using other application such as NetBeans and Dreamweaver. I hope you will help me to solve this problem. Thanks